# Quartz single job multiple triggers with specific start times does not work

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I'm trying to write a simple program which runs the same job at specific date times, the list of date times from a input file and here is my code:

```
SchedulerFactory schedFact = new org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory();
Scheduler sched = schedFact.getScheduler();

sched.start();

Map<JobDetail, List<Trigger>> jobAndTriggers = new HashMap<JobDetail, List<Trigger>> ();
List<Trigger> triggers = new ArrayList<Trigger> ();
JobDetail jobDetail = newJob (TestJob.class)
    .withIdentity(Constants.TEST_JOB_PREFIX, onstants.TEST_JOB_GRUOP_PREFIX)
    .build();

Trigger trigger = null;
int triggerIndex = 1;

for (Date date : dates) {
    trigger = newTrigger ()
       .withIdentity(Constants.SIMPLE_TRIGGER_PREFIX + triggerIndex, Constants.SIMPLE_TRIGGER_GROUP_PREFIX)
       .startAt(date)
       .withSchedule(simpleSchedule().withRepeatCount(0))
       .build();

   triggers.add(trigger);
}
jobAndTriggers.put(jobDetail, triggers);

sched.scheduleJobs (jobAndTriggers, true);
```

Now, when the program runs, say when I pass a list of date times like:
2013-03-13 12:21:33 | 
2013-03-13 12:21:37 | 
2013-03-13 12:22:41 | 
2013-03-13 12:22:45 | 
2013-03-13 12:23:49 |

The job will be only fired once which is the the last time stamp, I'm not sure what I did wrong, any help is appreciated. Following are some of the program logs:

```
12:19:33.265 [main] INFO  org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory - Quartz scheduler 'DefaultQuartzScheduler' initialized from default resource file in Quartz package: 'quartz.properties'
12:19:33.265 [main] INFO  org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory - Quartz scheduler version: 2.1.7
12:19:33.265 [main] INFO  org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler - Scheduler DefaultQuartzScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED started.
12:19:33.265 [DefaultQuartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread] DEBUG o.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread - batch acquisition of 0 triggers
12:19:33.265 [main] DEBUG c.s.r.s.s.TriggerAndJobBuilder - Triggers created:
12:19:33.265 [main] DEBUG c.s.r.s.s.TriggerAndJobBuilder - SIMPLE_TRIGGER_GROUP.SIMPLE_TRIGGER1 which will fire job at 2013-03-13 12:21:33
12:19:33.265 [main] DEBUG c.s.r.s.s.TriggerAndJobBuilder - SIMPLE_TRIGGER_GROUP.SIMPLE_TRIGGER1 which will fire job at 2013-03-13 12:21:37
12:19:33.265 [main] DEBUG c.s.r.s.s.TriggerAndJobBuilder - SIMPLE_TRIGGER_GROUP.SIMPLE_TRIGGER1 which will fire job at 2013-03-13 12:22:41
12:19:33.265 [main] DEBUG c.s.r.s.s.TriggerAndJobBuilder - SIMPLE_TRIGGER_GROUP.SIMPLE_TRIGGER1 which will fire job at 2013-03-13 12:22:45
12:19:33.265 [main] DEBUG c.s.r.s.s.TriggerAndJobBuilder - SIMPLE_TRIGGER_GROUP.SIMPLE_TRIGGER1 which will fire job at 2013-03-13 12:23:49
12:19:33.265 [DefaultQuartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread] DEBUG o.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread - batch acquisition of 1 triggers
12:19:34.109 [Timer-0] DEBUG org.quartz.utils.UpdateChecker - Checking for available updated version of Quartz...
12:19:34.265 [Timer-1] DEBUG org.quartz.utils.UpdateChecker - Checking for available updated version of Quartz...
12:19:49.265 [DefaultQuartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread] DEBUG o.q.simpl.PropertySettingJobFactory - Producing instance of Job 'TEST_GROUP.TEST_PING_JOB', class=com.test.TestJob
12:19:49.265 [DefaultQuartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread] DEBUG o.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread - batch acquisition of 0 triggers
12:23:49.265 [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-1] DEBUG org.quartz.core.JobRunShell - Calling execute on job TEST_GROUP.TEST_PING_JOB
12:23:49.265 [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-1] INFO  c.s.r.s.s.TestJob - Entered TestJob execute method at 2013-03-13 12:23:49
```

Comment: Problem fixed. I forgot to increase the variable triggerIndex which is part of trigger identifier. so basically I'm assigning "multiple" triggers with same identity, and Quartz overwrites "old" triggers with new settings.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have been assigning the same identifier for all the triggers so its the last one that is actually being considered.

```
triggerIndex = 1;
`Constants.SIMPLE_TRIGGER_PREFIX + triggerIndex`
```

Change this to something unique and there will be different triggers for each date you are sending in the list.